# Getting Blank Spaces in GridView Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I'm Getting blank Spaces in GridView.builder while displaying data from snapshots. I think its because I have applied condition inside GridView.builder so its leaving blank spaces. Is there any way to overcome this ?

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: fireStore,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }

      return  GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3, 
          mainAxisExtent: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1.5),
          itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            

            if (snapshot.data?.docs[index]["userType"] == "1" &&
                snapshot.data?.docs[index]["about"] != "") {
              return cardWidget(snapshot, index);
            } else {
              return SizedBox.shrink();
            }
          },
        );
    },
  );
```

[image: Image For Reference]

Comment: Remove the else condition to avoid that.

Comment: can't remove.. return is required. as "The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type" this error when removed else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are still returning an empty Widget (`SizedBox.shrink()`), that's why it is rendered as empty space. What you need to do is, prepare the valid data before returning the `GridView` widget.

e.g

```
final validData = snapshot.data?.docs.where((d)=> d['userType']==1 && d['about']!= 'data').toList();
```

Now you can use the `validData` to feed your `GridView` instead of `snapshot.data?.docs`.